# How to tell UINavigationBar to ignore a custom category?

Tags: iphone, background, categories, navigationbar

I'm having a little problem with customising an app's navigation bar and using an image picker.

I have a category that overrides the drawRect method of the app's nav bar, it changes the background image to a mostly white image. This works fine except when I call an image picker to let the user choose a pic from their library.

Firstly the image picker's nav bar displays the custom image but its title text is white which gets lost on the white background. And secondly the status bar is semi transparent which looks weird against the white navbar.

Is there anyway I can tell the image picker's nav bar to ignore the category I created and to use its default drawRect method?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make a category apply only sometimes. The way categories work means that you use it always or never. The only workaround I can think of is to somehow check inside of the categories' overridden method to see what instance you're in.

Comment: Thanks Moshe, I will check that out, something like if[superview isKindOfClass:UIImagePicker] {} im guessing.

Comment: @bennythemink - Yep, something like that, but use `NSClassFromString(@"UIImagePicker")` instead of just `UIImagePicker`.

Comment: Also, you can ask the image picker for its class by calling `class` on it. Very simple and you will know what to put in there.